# Foreach only receives the last element

Tags: php, zend-framework, foreach, zend-framework2, zend-form

I want a mail to be sent to all users in an array but it is only sent to the last user.

There must be something wrong with the `foreach` but I can't find what's causing this:

```
public function bulkmailAction()
{
    $users    = $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll();
    $projects = array();
    foreach ($users as $usersList)
    {
        $projects[$usersList->id] = $this->getProjectTable()->fetchJoin("projectuser", "projectuser.project=project.id", "user=$usersList->id");
    }
    $this->view->projects = $projects;
    $user = new Mailing();
    $form = new BulkMailForm($user);
    $form->get("submitbutton")->setValue("Send mail");
    $this->view->form = $form;
    $form->setInputFilter($user->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData(array_merge_recursive($this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),$this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()));
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($users as $usersList) {
                $formData = $form->getData();

                //redirect immediately without showing a view
                $subject = $formData["subject"];
                $message = $formData["message"];
                if ($message != strip_tags($message)) {
                    $message = \BOZA\Plugins\Functions::relToAbs($message);
                }
                $user->setSent(0);
                $user->setUser($usersList->id);
                $user->setName($usersList->name);
                $user->setSurname($usersList->surname);
                $user->setDate("0000-00-00");
                $user->setEmail($usersList->email);
                $user->setSubject($subject);
                $user->setHtml(true);
                $user->setMessage($message);
                $this->getTable("Mailing")->saveMailing($user);
                $this->view->setTerminal(true);
            }
        }
        $this->cache->success = "Mailing &laquo;".$user->toString()."&raquo; was successfully saved";
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin', array('controller' => 'mailing', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
    ...
```

Comment: This is one big method. If you break it apart into three to five (perhaps even more) methods that each are reposible for a certain part (gather user data, gather form data) [input] build form message, process inputs [procssing] and send email [output] and you interchange data between those methods with some data-strucutres, you should be able to more easily find out where the problem is. In any case, you need to proof the first line wrong in your code your own. Show us at which line the expectation you have is wrong (the first line you find, not just that after all it didn't work alone).

Comment: Your code shows no line where the actually message is send. As you overwrite the message over and over again and if the message is send automatically at the end, only the last message would be send. This could explain the behaviour you describe. Sending each message explicitly should then solve your issue already.

Answer (score 0):

You create the view as **BulkMailForm** form with one **Mailing** but you set the user multiple times and finally to the last one.

The **Mailing** is sent to the user set last. This is the standard bevaior. You need to add multiple recipients and not set a single one and/or create multiple mainlings, one per each user.

As you're using object in your code that are undefined, it's hard to give more specific guidance in an answer.

Comment: For the reasons answered I can't.  The objects you make use of are undefined to me.

Comment: What objects in particular do you want me to show ?

Comment: Do you see the bold names in my answer? these name the objects in question.

Comment: If that is your own code, please present your whole example in question in form of a github repository under a compatible license to the one use on  the Stackoverflow website. I don't work with pastebin links and your question.

Comment: Yes I am. In your current form your question is incomplete and not easily reproduceable. I even offer you to take the extra efforts into account to clone a git repo and give it a try. Something which is already borderline off-topic for a question here. Otherwise this sites TOS apply: Post as little code and data as necessary to demonstrate the issue. Do not take your production code but write a new example from scratch that demonstrates what you ask about *alone*. The example needs to be self-contained.